# How to configure Azure AD Oauth2 token endpoint for params vs. in-body?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-api-management

I'm using Azure AD to provide Oauth2 auth for an API.  Setup & config seemed to work fine for me, but a partner pointed out that the Oauth2 token endpoint doesn't like inline parameters -- it wants params passed in the HTTP body instead.

Ex: this call returns AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type':

https://login.microsoftonline.com/**my tennant**/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=**theclientid**&client_secret=**thesecret**&code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE'

But a post w/ the same params in the body as form data works just fine.  I believe Oauth is supposed to supposed to support the parameterized call (as shown in [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent)).
Is there somewhere in Azure to configure the Oauth2 endpoint to accept token parameters as post params vs. sending in the form body?

Answer (score 0):

```
he request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type':
```

Based on the response I would say you are setting the `content-type` header wrongly.

If you are posting this request : `https://login.microsoftonline.com/my tennant/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=theclientid&client_secret=thesecret&code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE'`  ensure that you are setting the `content-type` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

If you are the parameters in the body set the `content-type` as `application/json`